# Is there a way when displaying a dialog in Android to tell the app to show the pop up?

Tags: android, dialog

I have a full screen app that has buttons that want to have a custom drop down when they are clicked.  I was thinking of having a custom dialog show up that will have the options.  Is there a way to tell the dialog where to show up?

Comment: Do you mean like when you press drop down, you want to popup a dialog ?

Comment: I meant to tell the app where to show the pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a **Dialog** window you can change the position of the screen in which it will be displayed by doing something like this:

```
//Dialog reference
Dialog dialog;

//Instantiate here your dialog
dialog = ... ;

//Get window layout parameters reference
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams windowLayoutParams = window.getAttributes();

//Set the parameters you want
windowLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; //e.g. dialog's will be centered
window.setAttributes(windowLayoutParams);
```

You can instead use Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.TOP to display the dialog accordingly. Alternatively, for more specific positioning you can try setting attributes *"windowLayoutParams.x"* & *"windowLayoutParams.y"*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I am just going to use a Popup Menu for now.

Comment: Glad to help, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.